# Unwrapping continuous data into a single row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I have a piece of software that generates experimental data with a limited width, such that a string of data points will be wrapped into a series of rows limited to 4 columns wide in the final csv, rather than a single row per variable (A and B below) which is the form I need it in. (sample csv below)

```
A,1,3,3,2
,5,6,7,8
,9,10,11,12
,13,1,15,6
,17,1,2,20
B,1,2,3,7
,7,6,7,8
,9,10,11,12
,13,15,15,16
,17,18,3,2
```

In the real data this leaves me with about 53,000 rows a day to deal with, so I'd like to know if there's a function that will allow me to unwrap or re-dimension a given subset of data (each variable) into single rows. In the example above, the numbers following variable A would be combined into a single row while maintaining the order (ie 1,3,3,2,5...), as would B, and so on.

By request, the dput output to generate the above simplified example..

```
 structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("", 
 "A", "B"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(1L, 5L, 9L, 13L, 17L, 1L
 ), V3 = c(2L, 6L, 10L, 14L, 18L, 2L), V4 = c(3L, 7L, 11L, 15L, 
 19L, 3L), V5 = c(4L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 20L, 4L)), .Names = c("V1", 
 "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can this file be read in with `read.csv` and if so, can you `dput` what it gives you?  If it works at all, I'd guess that the 2nd-5th rows would have an NA at the beginning etc.  Also, try `readLines` and `dput(head(data)` in your question too.  The 2nd approach will certainly work.  Either one will require writing a small function to restore sanity to the data.  Sounds like the real world! And, is the start of a real data line always a upper case letter?

Comment: Hmm I'm really new to R so I'm not positive I follow. I do generally read in the data with read.csv. Generally all the rows between variable titles (which are always capitalized "A:, B:,.." to be exact appear blank. Is dput dependent on another library, or is it an argument within read.csv?

Comment: If you have read the data into a variable called `tst`, do `dput(head(tst))` and copy the result into your question above.  This shows us how the data is structured and gives a little piece of it for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an external tool to preprocess the file,

```
read.csv(pipe("sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\\n,//;ta' -e 'P;D' file.txt"), head=FALSE)
```

Essentially, `file.txt` is first processed by the unix tool `sed`, which performs a search-and-replace and returns the new content to R. The regular expression I adapted from [this page](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/sed1line.txt) to perform the following task:

```
  If a line begins with a comma, append it to the previous line 
  and replace the "," with nothing
```

---

**Edit (eddi -- note: this doesn't seem to work on Mac OS)** Here's how the following command is parsed by `sed`:

```
read.csv(pipe("sed ':a; N; s/\\n,/,/; t a; P; D' file.txt"), head=FALSE)

:a       # label (named "a") we're going to come back to
N        # read in the next line into pattern space, together with the newline character
s/\n,/,/ # if there is a newline followed by comma, delete the newline
t a      # go back to "a" and repeat until the above match fails (t stands for test)
P        # print everything in pattern space up to and including last \n
D        # delete everything in pattern space up to and including last \n
```

Comment: I love these but they are never transparent!

Comment: if younger kids [read xkcd comics](https://xkcd.com/208/), maybe they would become more natural to them; after all it's not so different from smileys and sms language. The grep man rises.

Comment: I'm afraid you've lost me with this one. I don't understand how to use that or what any of it means beyond read.csv :-/.

Answer (score 2):

grep, paste & read.table are pretty handy here.

```
# read in your data raw
X <- read.table("file")

# Any line that does NOT start with a comma, add a line break, 
# then re-read with read.table
read.table(text=paste(ifelse(grepl("^,", X), X, paste("\n", X)), collapse=""), sep=",")
```

Yields:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21  
1  A  1  3  3  2  5  6  7  8   9  10  11  12  13   1  15   6  17   1   2  20  
2  B  1  2  3  7  7  6  7  8   9  10  11  12  13  15  15  16  17  18   3   2
```

Comment: Check the order of the result: either you or I have parsed it wrong. Or nevermind, I see there is a difference between the OP's `dput` and the data in the question.  I used one and you used the other.

Comment: @BryanHanson, I used the dataset at the top of the OP, and you are right, it looks like they are different

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, I've got a lot of options to try out now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R solution. It uses `gsub()` and is short and easy to read (at least for me).

```
txt = readLines("file.txt")

# Join into one long string with newlines.
txt_long = paste(txt, collapse="\n")

# Remove newlines directly preceding a comma.
newtxt = gsub("\\n,", ",", txt_long)

read.table(text=newtxt, sep=",")
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21
# 1  A  1  3  3  2  5  6  7  8   9  10  11  12  13   1  15   6  17   1   2  20
# 2  B  1  2  3  7  7  6  7  8   9  10  11  12  13  15  15  16  17  18   3   2
```

Comment: Excellent: lean, but straightforward.  I love the range of answers this question has generated.  Lots of cleverness.  My answer is so brutish in comparison!  I did not know that there was a `text` argument to `read.table`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little ugly, but it was the first general strategy I thought of:

```
library(zoo)
library(plyr)
dat$V1 <- na.locf(dat$V1)
> ddply(dat,.(V1),function(x) c(t(as.matrix(x[,-1]))))
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20
1  1  3  3  2  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13   1  15   6  17   1   2  20
2  1  2  3  7  7  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  15  15  16  17  18   3   2
```

assuming that you read your data into an object called `dat` and used `na.strings = ""`. You could add on the `A`, `B` variable info afterwards, or possible stuff it into the anonymous `ddply` function.

There might be a way to reshape it directly using `dcast` but I couldn't think of a way.

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable. The array length for each variable is always the same, and unused positions appear 0 filled. They also always go in the same order, so if I have to reattach variable titles for row names it shouldn't be a problem. Given how new I am to R and programming in general, could you unpack the syntax a bit for me. I'm following up until ddply and on. I've tried using ddply before without luck because I can't seem to find an intuitive, non-programmer friendly explanation of many of the arguments. I specifically remember not understanding the function(x) bit. Thank you.

Comment: @user2510207 The third argument to `ddply` is a function to apply to each "chunk". You can pass the name of an existing function, or you can define a new function "inline", so to speak, as I've done here. This is referred to as an "anonymous function" because it exists only in the context of the `ddply` call.

Comment: Ok, cool. So is the function your defining c(t(as.matrix(x[,-1) and how exactly is it working to accomplish the task?

Comment: @user2510207 It just takes the values and (1) converts from data frame to matrix, minus the first column, (2) transpose the matrix, and (3) flatten the values into a single vector. The transpose is necessary because R stores matrices by column, rather than by row.

Comment: The function I wrote is essentially a manual version of what Joran describes.

Comment: Great, thanks guys. If I had the rep to upvote you all I would.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just love instrument manufacturers?

Here's an approach, I don't think it is quite perfect as I can't fully test w/o all the data, but you can.

**EDIT: updated function**

```
cleanData <- function(df) {
    good <- c() # holds indices of lines that start a row in the final data set
        # Find the 'starter' rows
    for (n in 1:nrow(df)) {
        if (df[n,1] != "") good <- c(good,n)
        }

    # Now go back and put it back together
    # Get one row in 1st to set dimensions

    newDat <- data.frame(mydat = df[(good[1]:(good[2])-1),])
    offset <- nrow(newDat)-1
    data <- as.numeric(t(as.matrix(newDat[,-1])))
    label <- df[1,1]
    newDat <- data.frame(data)
    names(newDat) <- label
    #print(newDat) # OK

    # now do them all
    for (n in 2:length(good)) {
        use <- good[n]:(good[n] + offset)
        data <- as.numeric(t(as.matrix(df[use,-1])))
        label <- df[good[n],1]
        newCol <- data.frame(data)
        names(newCol) <- label
        newDat <- cbind(newDat, newCol)
        }

    newDat
    }
```

Copy and paste the function above into `R`, then do `newTst <- cleanData(tst)` where `tst` is your data frame from `read.csv`.  If it works, take a look at `newTst` or do `str(newTst)`.

On your test data it gives:

```
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ A: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ B: num  1 2 3 4 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the time Bryan, that's sizable chunk of code to write to help out. I'll give these approaches a try.

Comment: It was a good puzzle instead of doing the work I should be doing!